# ld: library not found for -lCocoaAsyncSocket - React Native

Tags: ios, react-native

I have created a new react native project and when I try to run the app within an iOS emulator it always crashes.

When I open the .xcworkspace within Xcode I get the following error.

[image: error]

I have tried to update the search paths but this has not worked, I have also tried to reinstall pods but this hasn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

This must be fixed on the framework side, however, the solution is the following steps:

1. On the Xcode bring the `Build Settings` tab
2. Find the `Search Paths` and then try to modify `Library search paths`
3. Add `${inherited}` to the first of the list. *It's important to be the first*
4. Delete the `build` folder inside the `ios` folder of the project
5. Try to run the project again

It must fix the issue

Answer (score -1):

This issue is basically related to the wrongly linking classes. Please follow these steps:

1. check make sure, you have install all the pods.
2. Please check your .js files, and check your import statements. To be make sure , every import statement package is installed in your project
3. clean project
4. Rebuild again

Comment: i have checked all this and still have the problem

Answer (score -1):

I can see that you state you have already checked search paths, but I had this same issue, and it was resolved by adding `"${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}"` as `recursive` to my Library Search Paths, under `<Project>` > `Build Settings` > `Library Search Paths`. However, now I'm stuck on the linker instruction `-lcrypto`, so it's not a complete solution.